# How to check JHipster environment

Tags: jhipster

Can someone tell me if this is the correct way to check the current environment when using JHipster ?

```
public DwollaService(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, Environment env) throws Exception {
    this.dwolla = applicationProperties.dwolla;
    this.env = env;
    
    Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
    Boolean isProd = activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION);
    this.dwollaClient = new Dwolla(
        this.dwolla.getKey(),
        this.dwolla.getSecret(),
        (isProd) ? DwollaEnvironment.PRODUCTION : DwollaEnvironment.SANDBOX 
    );
}
```

Comment: It's a way to do it yes but usually I prefer to avoid mixing the concept of prod profile with environment because you could want to run in prod profile on multiple environments (i.e. staging, qualification, integration). So I usually define another profile per environment so that application-prod.yml contains only properties that are common to all environments. Also it depends on where you store secrets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works but following is the better way to identify prod environment(In fact spring deprecated [checking active profiles based on strings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#acceptsProfiles-java.lang.String...-)).

```
isProd = env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION));
```